# Saving String data to SharedPreference then append to Uri

Tags: android

I want to make a Uri String like `"http://almond.com/iOS/html/best.php?best_id=30241,15890"`

The parameters of best_id (30241 and 15890) is retrieved like this from a custom url

```
       String[] path = uri.getPath().split("/");
        String sid = path[path.length - 1];
```

The problem is I want to keep appending  a parameter with a comma after a click.
But I'm not sure how I can append a parameter to a url string and save it to the same sharedPreference.

sample

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor savestamp = pref.edit();


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < sid.length; i++) {
            sb.append(sid[i]).append(",");
        }
        savestamp.putString("params2", sb.toString());
```

I'm trying to do it but since I'm a total noob,just googling wont help.  I would be grateful if the pros here can help me out.

Comment: is my answer worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit after putting the values.

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor savestamp = pref.edit();


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < sid.length; i++) {
            sb.append(sid[i]).append(",");
        }
        savestamp.putString("params2", sb.toString());

savestamp.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

please add `savestamp.commit();` after `savestamp.putString` method then only it saved to `SharedPreference`